# Argument might be null for getSharedPreferences().getString(name, default) with nonNull default string?

Tags: android

I don't understand why Android Studio is not able to tell that, although SharedPreferences declares the defValue of getString as @Nullable, the current value is actually not null!

The result of the following call:

```
  myFunction(getSharedPreferences().getString(MY_SETTING_NAME.name(), "This string is not null"))
```

will trigger a warning:

```
 Argument might be null
```

How can it be? Since defValue is actually not null and we know it...

Answer (score 0):

The Android framework does not use [Kotlin contracts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#contracts) and cannot change the `@Nullable` annotation on the return value based on whether the `defValue` you pass is null or not.

As an alternative, you should consider using Kotlin's [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) and writing code such as:

```
myFunction(getSharedPreferences().getString(MY_SETTING_NAME.name(), null)
    ?: "This string is not null")
```

Which correctly evaluates as non-null.

Comment: I am not using Kotlin, just Java

Comment: Then you can just leave out any nullability annotation on `myFunction` and treat it as non-null within your method just fine

Comment: @ianhanniballake so, what's the downside of using something like  `myFunction(getSharedPreferences().getString(MY_SETTING_NAME.name(), "This string is not null")!!)` If we know that `getString` should not return null in this particular case.

Comment: @mikehc - if *you* know, that's fine. The compiler doesn't know that passing in a non-null `defValue` changes the nullability of the return type. If `myFunction` was implemented in Kotlin, then you *cannot* pass a possibly null value to a function that expects a non-null value. In Java, you have a third option - unknown nullability where *you* know the nullability but the compiler doesn't know or attempt to know.

Comment: Then why can't I just mute this warning? Is it because they want to push users to migrate to kotlin where this will be a real warning?

Comment: @Myoch - It isn't a warning in Kotlin - it does not compile at all. You won't get this warning if your `myFunction` doesn't have a `@NonNull` annotation on it, which isn't required for Java code. If you insist on annotating your method parameter, you can certainly suppress the warning.